# Generate Asp.Net Bundle based on value in the querystring

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I'd like to be able to generate an Asp.Net bundle at runtime but change the contents of it based on the result of a database query.

Here's the scenario: working within a CMS system, I build up a page of content based on lots of little "snippets" of Html, each of which can potentially have their own set of stylesheets and javascript files. Each content page can be created at runtime by the user, so at design time I don't know which assets I will need.

So what I would like to be able to do is something like this:

```
@Styles.Render("~/contentPage/?id=2")
```

Where `id` is the page ID that the snippets are part of. Then, I would like to be able to take that ID, load the page, load the snippet entities which are associated with it, get a set of stylesheet names then produce the bundle.

Is this possible within the current confines of the framework? If not, is it possible to build my own handler for this which leverages the power of the existing framework to do the minification and all the other cool stuff that I get out of the box?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, it should be relatively easy to write your own bundler and minifier. It does not deal with your specific problem but I have written a post some time ago that can give you some ideas on where to start: http://tallmaris.com/advanced-bundling-and-minification-of-coffeescripts-in-mvc4/

Comment: @Tallmaris Thanks for this - thanks to your blog post I was able to come up with a similar solution which works well. It was actually embarassingly simple, now that I've done it!

Comment: Good to know! You may want to share your solution as an answer here for other people. ;)

Comment: Yep, I'm planning to. I just need a little time to write it up :-)